# Is there a websocket URL in Ethereum classic like in Ethereum?

Tags: events, react, ethereum-classic, websocket

Can anyone tell me whether or not there is a WebSocket URL to deal with smart contract events in Ethereum Classic especially? I know ethereum supports WebSockets and we can easily listen to events from smart-contract with web3. But how about ethereum classic?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no idea.

It's not a functionality of the blockchain protocol. It's a functionality in the client nodes.

So the Ethereum itself doesn't care how people interact with it, as long as the data is valid. The clients provide the means for users to interact with the blockchain. So it depends on the client implementation.

Unfortunately I have no idea whether the clients support WebSockets in ETC. If I had to guess, I would guess yes they do, since ETC is not that old-fashioned (yet).

Comment: Yes they do. But yes it's a client feature, nothing related to the Ethereum protocol itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you see ethereum then infura does provide the WebSocket URL as in the screenshot below.
I am then instantiating web3 with this Websocket URL. But I tried searching such Websocket URL for ETC but couldn't get the one. That's why it's really frustrating. With this now I can listen to the ethereum smart-contract events. I want to do the same in ETC contracts.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://rivet.cloud/. Please go the Dashboard and select the Ethereum Classic. Then you can generate the rpc urls for the Ethereum Classic chain.